# how to make laravel export excel without model

Tags: excel, ajax, laravel, model, export

i have already read laravel-export excel. but my project is different, where my project didn't have model. how to make export excel in laravel without make model? laravel8 and maatwebsite3

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ExportExcel implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

what should I type in export controller, exportexcel and the download button

Answer (score 0):

You could always import using `DB` facade.

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => $row[0],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you would always create empty shell models, to do insertions. I often do this, if i have to cleanup `wordpress` data and want the `Laravel` facades for ease of use.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Which would enable the following from the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html) to work.

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new User([
        'name' => $row[0],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: what **$rows** means?

Comment: rows are from the method definition that excel package provides, this will represent all the rows in the csv

Comment: The question is about export, not import.